# iOS Swift: How to create object like UIAlertView that seemingly nils itself out after dismissal

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to setup an alert view. The user of this class should only have to alloc a new alert (customize it) and show it. When the alert is dismissed, I want the reference to the alert essentially set to nil, but I don't want the user to have to do this. How does Apple do this with the UIAlertView? You simply create a UIAlertView and show it, you never have to nil it out after dismissal.

Comment: Your title is in contradiction with the  question's body. You can do what the title asks. But you can't do what you describe in the question body.

Fix one of those, I guess the title is wrong...

Comment: Question/title changed.

Comment: Well now that this is settled, see my main answer, which explains why this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a strong reference to itself. For example, assume you have two methods `show:` and `dismiss:`. Show could set the value of a strong property to self. Then later, `dismiss:` can set that reference to null, allowing ARC to take over and release the reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Objects are not in control of their ownership. The owners i.e. objects that hold a strong reference to the object are in control of it.

If a user (really an object) creates an alert object, only the user can abandon the alert. The alert cannot make itself abandoned from the user.

This would wreak complete havoc to ARC and would rendered memory management rules useless. 
If we want to get a bit poetical, i would say it's **hell broke loose in Objectville.**